# How can I give EL expressions as parameters in nested jsp 2.0 tags?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I want to do something like this to call a JSP 2.0 tag:

```
<mytags:foo abc="<%=def%>">
  <mytags:bar ghi="<%=jkl%>"/>
</mytags:foo>
```

Where Strings `def` and `jkl` are defined earielr in the jsp file.  Suppose my tag files look like this:

`foo.tag`:

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<%@ attribute name="abc" required="true" %>
<div class="${abc}">
  <jsp:doBody/>
</div>
```

`bar.tag`:

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<%@ attribute name="ghi" required="true" %>
<div>${ghi}</div>
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
<div class="def">
<div>jkl</div>
</div>
```

(assuming the variables `def` and `jkl` were initialized to `def` and `jkl`, respectively, in the calling JSP file.)

The outer tag gets its attribute just fine (`<div class="def">`) but the inner one fails.

Is this possible?  I am getting errors that jkl cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the `body-content="scriptless"` attribute in the tag directive. This means that the body surrounded by the tag can't contain scriptlet code (the `<% %>` stuff). You need to use EL.

It works for me if I change the stuff in the JSP to:

```
  <c:set var="def" value="def"></c:set>
  <c:set var="jkl" value="jkl"></c:set>

  <mytags:foo abc="${def}">
      <mytags:bar ghi="${jkl}"/>
  </mytags:foo>
```

Note that I need to add
`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`